# Mysql 5.5 crash on Debian 6 - won't start because of corruption

Tags: mysql

After a server crash my mysql dB crashes.  During startup it produces 36,000 lines in syslog, and I have no idea how to repair this.  I had master slave replication setup , but I have no idea what to do with the slave.

The databases contain email server records and no one can use Email anymore.

The versions are :

```
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                     4.016-1                          Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient16                      5.1.66-0+squeeze1                MySQL database client library
rc  libmysqlclient18                      5.5.30-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database client library
ii  libqt4-sql-mysql                      4:4.6.3-4+squeeze1               Qt 4 MySQL database driver
ii  mysql-client                          5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-client-5.5                      5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.5                 5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                          5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server                          5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
rc  mysql-server-5.1                      5.1.58-1~dotdeb.1                MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-5.5                      5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.5                 5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0                MySQL database server binaries
```

All I would like to do is rollback any trnasactions and then get this dB running again.  I've searched on Google for lots of help, but they refer to many items that I simplay do not understand how to use. For example I tried innochecksum, and the man page states just type the command, and then within it tell it to scan tables files: There are no table files in `/var/lib/mysql/tablename/*`, and this command is not interactive.  Hence the confusion.

Can anyone help me out here because I really an in at the deep end.

Many thanks, 
Simon

The syslog mysql messages read:
  I cannot post the messages because serverfault thinks these are links, and I do not have permission to paste linkes, even though it's the contents of syslog.

Comment: Hi,   I have put the syslog into pastebin.   http://pastebin.com/1nBwk9bk

Comment: Here is my MY.CNF file ( serverfault wont' let me paste it into here:( )      http://pastebin.com/x2N6iZad

Comment: I have managed to get the dB open with [mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 2
I did a mysqldump for all tables, and restarted with innodb_force_recordy but still have the same old mess :(

Comment: Please link to the MySQL bug report you should have filed before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tables have serious corruption. At this point, you'd need to restore them from backup or import the dumps that you were able to get. You do have backups, right?

Comment: I had a master/slave replication set up.    I can import the dumps that I made.          Also, the database is now running with "innodb_force_recovery = 2"  which means that processes can read from the database tables (e.g postfix/spamassassim/roundcube/) but I don't think they can update.  If the data works for reading then why cannot this be opened for writing?  I should have thought that if read-only works, then setting the state o.k, or rolling back uncompleted transactions should be acceptable. Unsure how to do this.

Comment: Note that SUbject title is misleading and I should be grateful if this were changed like "mysql 5.5 crash on Debian 6 - won't start because of corruption",  if you could?

Comment: As I said, you're better off cleaning out everything and starting over. Create a new database and import the dumps. At this point, that's all I can think of to get it running again. The `innodb_force_recovery` has a safety feature which disables modifying the tables.

Comment: OK Shall do this.  In the meantime I ran a mysqlrepair -A -a, and this said all was well, which I don't really believe :)

Comment: I see that some databases in /var/lib/mysql/$database have different files:  some just have .fmt files for each table, and other have e.g host.frm host.MYD  host.MYI. Could this be dependent on Engine type?

Comment: Is there a way to find out which database had been corrupted?  It'd be a shame to dump and then import databases whose structure is fine.

Comment: It looks like *all* the databases were affected since the crash references metadata related to mysql itself. And yes, different engines have different files related to it.

Comment: Oh shoot. /deep breath.  I have backups created by an rsync... and data from the slave site.   but since the mysql db itself had been corrupted, then I cannot see how this helps, because the whole /var/lib/mysql is pretty much useless.  ( I could leave this in read-only until I manage to work out how to continue, but I think I'll have to rm the whole lot and reinstall again if this is that hosed).

Comment: I deleted /var/lib/mysql/* and copied an older copy in and this worked well.  We had some loss of data, obviously.  Thank-you everyone for your comments and help.